# Android Facebook SDK version 4.5.0 - Post text on wall

Tags: android, facebook

In my app having some text, if user tap on SHARE button i would like to share that text to FB. From 4.5 we are having Link,PHOTO sharing options. Is there any way to send only user defined text?. I would like to share app text content to FB.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using android studio u cannot direct share plain text in fb.. u need to use facebook API for sharing text and images.. if u want to share URL then using intent u can share.. but for text u need use fb api –

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android